# How to install smalot/pdfparser on plesk server because its not working when i put the folder on pleask server in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have installed the Smalot/PdfParser on local server it's working good but when I transferred the library on my Plesk server then its showing that Smalot/PdfParser/Parser not found

I am trying to connect the library on controller

using this method
new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();

and getting the output is production. ERROR: Class 'src\Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found.

Comment: Have you installed the `Smalot/PdfParser` on the Plesk server

Comment: Yes I have installed the Smalot/PdfParser on the Plesk Server.

Comment: If you have already installed the package, then make sure that you have included the autoload file in your PHP file, which registers the necessary namespaces and autoloads classes. You can include the autoload file by adding require_once `'vendor/autoload.php';` at the beginning of your PHP file.

Comment: Yes, sir, I have tried all these things, and after all of this, it's showing the error. each and every possibility I have tried. but I failed to integrate this on Plesk, and the same code and library work properly on my local server.